# Arbitrary length of input/output for Recurrent Neural Network (LSTM)

Tags: python, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

This is [an example](https://pythonhosted.org/neurolab/ex_newelm.html) of use [Elman Recurrent Neural Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network#Elman_networks_and_Jordan_networks) from [Neurolab Python Library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/neurolab):

```
import neurolab as nl
import numpy as np

# Create train samples
i1 = np.sin(np.arange(0, 20))
i2 = np.sin(np.arange(0, 20)) * 2

t1 = np.ones([1, 20])
t2 = np.ones([1, 20]) * 2

input = np.array([i1, i2, i1, i2]).reshape(20 * 4, 1)
target = np.array([t1, t2, t1, t2]).reshape(20 * 4, 1)

# Create network with 2 layers
net = nl.net.newelm([[-2, 2]], [10, 1], [nl.trans.TanSig(), nl.trans.PureLin()])
# Set initialized functions and init
net.layers[0].initf = nl.init.InitRand([-0.1, 0.1], 'wb')
net.layers[1].initf= nl.init.InitRand([-0.1, 0.1], 'wb')
net.init()
# Train network
error = net.train(input, target, epochs=500, show=100, goal=0.01)
# Simulate network
output = net.sim(input)

# Plot result
import pylab as pl
pl.subplot(211)
pl.plot(error)
pl.xlabel('Epoch number')
pl.ylabel('Train error (default MSE)')

pl.subplot(212)
pl.plot(target.reshape(80))
pl.plot(output.reshape(80))
pl.legend(['train target', 'net output'])
pl.show()
```

In this example it's **merging** **2 unit length input** and also it's merging **2 unit length output**. After that it's training the network with these **merged arrays**.

First of all it doesn't seem like the schema that I got from [here](https://iamtrask.github.io/2015/11/15/anyone-can-code-lstm/):

[image]

My main question is;

I have to train the network with **arbitrary length of** **inputs** and **outputs** like these:

- Arbitrary length inputs to fixed length outputs
- Fixed length inputs to arbitrary length outputs
- Arbitrary length inputs to arbitrary length outputs

At this point this will come to your mind: "Your answer is [Long short-term memory networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory)."

And I know It but [Neurolab](https://pythonhosted.org/neurolab/) is easy to use because of it's [good features](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/neurolab). Particularly, it is exceptionally **Pythonic**. So **I'm insisting on** using **Neurolab Library** for my problem. But if you suggest me *another library* like Neurolab with better [LSTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory) functionality, **I will accept it**.

Eventually, How can I rearrange this example for arbitrary length of inputs and outputs?

I don't have the best understanding about RNNs and LSTMs so please be explanatory.

Comment: Solved the problem or can I still answer ?

Comment: @RajarsheeMitra You can still answer.

Comment: what is the answer of this? Using  arbitrary length of inputs and outputs?

Comment: @Uzair I answered my own question. Please check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43688984/2104879

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long time when I look at this question of mine today, I can see it was a question of a person with lack of understanding about neural networks.

Matrix multiplication is the basic math at the heart of neural networks. You can not simply change the shape of input matrix because it changes the shape of the product and breaks the consistency among the dataset.

[image]

Neural networks are always trained with fixed length of input and output. Here is a very simple neural network implementation that using nothing but numpy's dot product to feedforward:

```
import numpy as np

# sigmoid function
def nonlin(x,deriv=False):
    if(deriv==True):
        return x*(1-x)
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

# input dataset
X = np.array([  [0,0,1],
                [0,1,1],
                [1,0,1],
                [1,1,1] ])

# output dataset            
y = np.array([[0,0,1,1]]).T

# seed random numbers to make calculation
# deterministic (just a good practice)
np.random.seed(1)

# initialize weights randomly with mean 0
syn0 = 2*np.random.random((3,1)) - 1

for iter in xrange(10000):

    # forward propagation
    l0 = X
    l1 = nonlin(np.dot(l0,syn0))

    # how much did we miss?
    l1_error = y - l1

    # multiply how much we missed by the 
    # slope of the sigmoid at the values in l1
    l1_delta = l1_error * nonlin(l1,True)

    # update weights
    syn0 += np.dot(l0.T,l1_delta)

print "Output After Training:"
print l1
```

credit: http://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/12/basic-python-network/

Comment: I have two nd arrays, first array size is (45,1707) and second array size is (1707,)...do u have any idea how can i train these two arrays?

Comment: @Uzair you need to flatten the first array from (45,1707) to (76815,) using [numpy.ndarray.flatten](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html). I assume that first array is your input and the second one is your output/target. (76815,) is a huge array size and probably it will be practically impossible to train that network.

Comment: Yes i try this but its size is very large how can i train? Is there any way to train?